# How old was Carl in The Walking Dead?

Tags: character, the-walking-dead

According to the *The Walking Dead* wiki Carl was 12 years old when the show started, although the actor was 10-11 at the time. How old is Carl when season 8 started? He has a visible beard by then and got about as tall as Rick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real world, he aged 8 years, whereas in  TV world I believe [based on Kirkman's comments](https://comicbook.com/thewalkingdead/2018/02/19/the-walking-dead-time-passed-carl-age-/) no more than 5 years which if he started out around 11 would make him 16 at most? Lots of inconsistencies in his and Judith's aging but puberty in a post-apocalyptic world must be tough...all that stress ages you quicker I guess while Judith as a baby is still protected and shielded.

Comment: "Based on Kirkman's comments" - what comments? If you can provide evidence from the show's creators to back up your answer, that would really help improve it.

Comment: I assume by "the real world" you mean the comics?  I haven't noticed any zombie apocalypses in the REAL world, anyway :P

Comment: @Steve-O: By "the real world" I assume he means the actor, Chandler Riggs, aging 8 years over the course of the show.